# CoreBluetooth sometimes not detecting CBPeripheral unless accessing Control Center/Notification Center

Tags: ios, swift, core-bluetooth, cbperipheral

I'm working on an app which connects to a BLE Peripheral, and I sometimes run into a very strange issue, where the Peripheral is never found by the CentralManager. However, when pulling down Notification Center on the device, or when swiping up Control Center, the Peripheral immediately shows up and connects.

I've tried to find the cause of this problem, but so far I haven't been able to find anything. Apart from `willResignActive` and `didBecomeActive`, no other lifecycle functions seem to be called (AFAIK), but in neither of those functions I do anything other than printing that they've been called.

I already made sure to use `self.centralManager.scanForPeripherals(withServices: nil, options: [CBCentralManagerScanOptionAllowDuplicatesKey: true])` in case I somehow screw up and not detect an initial scan.

Does anyone know what might be the cause of this, and how Control Center or Notification Center's influence on the app might solve this problem?

Thanks!

EDIT: Some extra code that might help find the issue. However, I know that when the problem happens, both `discoveredPeripheral` and `connectedPeripheral` are `nil`.

`didConnect`

```
func centralManager(_ central: CBCentralManager, didConnect peripheral: CBPeripheral) {
    if centralManager.isScanning {
        centralManager.stopScan()
    }

    self.connectedPeripheral = peripheral
    self.discoveredPeripheral?.delegate = self

    debugPrint("\(Date()): Connected \(peripheral)")
    peripheral.discoverServices(nil)

    DispatchQueue.main.async {
        self.rssiTimer = Timer.scheduledTimer(timeInterval: 1.0, target: self, selector: #selector(self.readPeripheralRSSI), userInfo: nil, repeats: true)
    }
}
```

`didDiscover`

```
func centralManager(_ central: CBCentralManager, didDiscover peripheral: CBPeripheral, advertisementData: [String: Any], rssi RSSI: NSNumber) {
        if peripheral.name == global.qnr && discoveredPeripheral == nil {
            centralManager.stopScan()
            debugPrint(
                "Discovered \(peripheral). " +
                "Initiating authentication sequence with \n" +
                "\tQNR: \(global.qnr)\n" +
                "\tSessionKey: \(global.sessionKey)\n" +
                "\tToken: \(global.bluetoothToken)")

            if self.discoveredPeripheral == nil || self.discoveredPeripheral != peripheral {
                self.discoveredPeripheral = peripheral
                self.centralManager.connect(peripheral, options: nil)
            }
        }
    }
```

`startScanning`

```
func scanForPeripherals() {
    if !centralManager.isScanning && global.sessionKey != "" {
        let services = [CONSTANTS.CBUUID]
        self.centralManager.scanForPeripherals(withServices: services, options: [CBCentralManagerScanOptionAllowDuplicatesKey: true])
    }
}
```

Comment: `discoveredPeripheral` and `connectedPeripheral` are nil because of the method `didConnect` not called at all. This `didConnect` method is called when you connect to a device.

Comment: You are scanning for devices with `scanForPeripherals()` method. What happens next? How do you connect with the device?

Comment: After `scanForPeripherals()` start scanning, I should get callbacks on my `didDiscover peripheral`-function (there I also `connect`), however, I _sometimes_ don't get any callbacks on that function with the correct `name`, until I swipe Notification Center or Control Center (which triggers `willResignActive()`)

Answer (score 0):

You have to notify the delegate when a device(s) discovered. This is how I handle. I remove the previously added devices when I discover and then add or re-add. Once the discovered devices are added to the array, then reload the table if you are using the tableView to display.

```
func centralManager(_ central: CBCentralManager, didDiscover peripheral: CBPeripheral, advertisementData: [String : Any], rssi RSSI: NSNumber) {
    if (peripheral.name != nil) {
        // remove previously added devices
        items.removeAll()
        items.append(peripheral)
    }
    // Set RSSI to custom peripheral signal property
    customPeripheral.signal = RSSI
    // Notify delegate for change in data.
    NotificationCenter.default.post(name: .reload, object: nil)
}

// Extension for reload tableView when peripheral array is updated
extension Notification.Name {
    static let reload = Notification.Name("reload")
}
```

In your case. You notify the notification to connect to your device once the scan is complete and the device is found.

```
// Connect with peripheral
func connectPeripheral(peripheral: CBPeripheral) {
    centralManager.connect(peripheral, options: nil)
    centralManager.stopScan()
    print("Connecting")
}
```

Comment: I already do this. I filter for the expected name, connect to it, discover services/characteristics, and tell my delegate. So I don't think this will solve it, unfortunately.

Comment: Did you give a try? And, it will be difficult to sort out your problem if you do not show us your code. What you did and what you did not.

Comment: Do you display the list of devices in the table?

Comment: Nope, there is exactly one device that it should connect to, which is the one with the specific name (it's a car actually), so I only have to know the information for that specific peripheral.

Comment: Same, I've also updated my answer with some code that I use. The problem is not that I don't tell my delegate, it's that my CentralManager sometimes doesn't find the peripheral. When I check the local variables of my class (`discoveredPeripheral` and `connectedPeripheral`), they stay `nil` until a force close, or until Control Center / Notification Center show up...

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/172303/discussion-between-afstkla-and-maihan-nijat).